# VBA change array data with with If statement

Tags: excel, vba

**Mission:** Calculate matching cable types and check to see how many reels I need depending on the length, qty and reel length.

**Currently:** My code will check the reel length on the appropriate line but it check it against all of the different types of cables.

**How Can I:** Change the array fill with only matching items?

I am checking to see if C = J and D = K and E = L. This is because left side of the sheet are individual lengths and the right are the total lengths.

`rInpStk` is the Reel length total.

```
'Fill array with cable lengths
For i = 0 To UBound(CutArr, 1)
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 7 To lastrow 'Commenting out this If will get me the same result
        If Cells(x, 3).Value = rInpStk.Offset(, -5) And _
           Cells(x, 4).Value = rInpStk.Offset(, -4) And _
           Cells(x, 5).Value = rInpStk.Offset(, -3) Then 'This does nothing
            CutArr(i, 0) = rInputCuts.Cells(i + 1, 2) 'I want these to only populate the same cable types
            CutArr(i, 1) = rInputCuts.Cells(i + 1, 1) 'If there is not a match then dont add that rows data to the array
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x
Next i
```

[image: Example of Data]

Do I need to do an AutoFilter? If so how would I implement that.

After it's done I want it to continue to the next cable type.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Difficult to answer this without knowing what your data looks like

Comment: Where does `CurArr` come from, and where is `rInpStk` pointing to?

Comment: FWIW, looking at your data, you can use a formula like `SUMIFS($A$7$:$A$10000,$C$7$:$C$10000,$J7,$D$7$:$D$10000,$K7,$E$7$:$E$10000,$L7)` and copy down. Change `10000` to suit your data limit. In VBA, you can use `dictionary` object to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to create the table you show under your **TOTALS** header, you can do this easily using `Power Query` which has been available since Excel 2010.

And if your data changes in your first table, a simple 'Refresh' will update the results table, and it will automatically adjust for changes in the amount of data, or types, in your first table.

- Create a custom column of Total Length which is the product of your source data length*qty.
- Then group by columns 3-7, with the `SUM` aggregate function.
- Delete the unnecessary columns, and rearrange to get the desired column order.

This can all be done from the UI with the Custom Column formula of `[LENGTH]*[QTY]`

**MCode**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="cableTbl"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"LENGTH", Int64.Type}, {"QTY", Int64.Type}, {"TYPE", type text}, {"SIZE", type text}, {"COL", type text}, {"CU ID", Int64.Type}, {"MAX ID", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [LENGTH]*[QTY]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"LENGTH", "QTY"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"TYPE", "SIZE", "COL", "CU ID", "MAX ID"}, {{"LENGTH", each List.Sum([Custom]), type number}}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"LENGTH", "TYPE", "SIZE", "COL", "CU ID", "MAX ID"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

**Results**

[image]